Problem with mathematical formulas in gap statistic
I'm studying the article "Estimating the number of clusters in a data set via the gap statistic" by R. Tibshirani, G. Walther and T.Hastie: https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/63/2/411/7083348.
In this part, I can't understand what the mathematical formula comes from and what pn/12 and 2/p symbolize to me.
Could someone explain to me?
Below I put the requested part of the article:

